# local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found

Tags: android, api, mobile, google-play-services, vision

I'm new at Google Mobile Vision api and I've been using barcode detector class to detect barcodes. The app works fine but it does not work in my android 4.2.2 phone. I've updated the play services to v10.0.1 but still no good. When connected to android studio with debugger I get the message: 'local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found'.
I've tried the app in other android 4.2.2 device. It works, but for some reason it doesn't work in mine.
Can anyone help me with the above error? Some libraries I'm missing perhaps?

Answer (score 10):

for me, the device doesn't have google-play-service. I just download (google-play-service) from Google Play Store and update software. (oppo)

Answer (score 2):

Free up some memory and you should be good to go.I was facing the same issue when I had around 800MB of free memory. I made it to 2GB and its working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is emulator. Because it doesn't have provider, you should connect custom phone or build apk then try on your phone.

Comment: what do you mean by it does not have provider?

Answer (score 2):

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The improved answer is to add this line to your `app > build.gradle > dependencies`

Answer (score 1):

I had the Google play App disable,
so i turned it enable and then i deleted my app data and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am also suffered with the same issue. I have resolved in the following way

**Clear the app data from settings.**

Its working for me.

source : https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/164

Answer (score 0):

In .NET MAUI I resolved this problem by replacing library:

```
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite
```

to

```
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads
```