# local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found - flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

[my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PS4uP.jpg)

i'm trying to setup firebase (firestore)  and i try to install google play service in emulator but does't work  - and i try to https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/10031 but doesn't work [Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found. Flutter Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73687618/local-module-descriptor-class-for-com-google-android-gms-providerinstaller-dynam).
i'm follow the tutorial on youtube how to connecting flutter with firestore.but i met this problem and i use flutter version 2 and the tutorial in youtube teach me to make database development

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.