# i got this error while try to connect with firebase in flutter ,can any one explain what is the mistake i did,and too correct it

Tags: flutter

W/DynamiteModule(14350): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule(14350): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller(14350): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/xample.firebas(14350): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/TetheringManager(14350): registerTetheringEventCallback:com.example.firebase
V/NativeCrypto(14350): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 295 native methods...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40956265/local-module-descriptor-class-for-com-google-android-gms-vision-dynamite-not-fou)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.